# ASP.NET Ajax function Sys.Component.create() or $create() gets wrong parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I am using Sys.Component.create() function to create an elements in my page. The first time I use this function to create an object of a class, this function calls the initializes the object with correct parameters. However, the second time when I use this function to create another instance of the same class it gets wrong parameters (the same parameters that I passed to it the first time).

```
var calculationDetailsElement = $(".someClass")[0];
$create(CalculationDetails, { calculation: this.calculation, isCreateCart: true, element_id: this.calculation.Id }, null, null, calculationDetailsElement);
```

For example, if I set element_id to 10 in the first time, it will have the value of 10 the second time also. Even though I pass a different value.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue happened because the defined object (CalculationDetails) had some errors, so it would throw an error before the $create function is completely done.